# How to animate in CSS with Keyframes

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a problem.
My menue should "slide" from left to right, so I have wrote some CSS:

```
.animate-in {
    animation-name: menue-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animate-out {
    animation-name: menue-out;
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menue-in {
    from { transform: translateX(-100%);}
    to { transform: translateX(0%);}
  }
@keyframes menue-out {
    from { transform: translateX(0%);}
    to { transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

The Keyframe which is called "menue-in" to move the menue from left to right works fine BUT my keyframe "menus-out" doesn't...

Could somebody help me please?

Here is my JS Code...

```
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0];
    let navigation = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation__mobile")[0];
    let showing = false;
    toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigation.classList.toggle("d-flex");
        if(showing == false) {
            navigation.classList.remove("animate-out");
            navigation.classList.add("animate-in");
            showing = true;
        }
        else {
            navigation.classList.remove("animate-in");
            navigation.classList.add("animate-out");
            showing = false;
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to stop the animation at last frame.

Here's a snippet for your case.
Enjoy. :)

```js
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let toggle = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0];
    let navigation = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation__mobile")[0];
    let showing = false;
    toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigation.classList.toggle("d-flex");
        if(showing == false) {
            navigation.classList.remove("animate-out");
            navigation.classList.add("animate-in");
            showing = true;
        }
        else {
            navigation.classList.remove("animate-in");
            navigation.classList.add("animate-out");
            showing = false;
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.animate-in {
    animation-name: menue-in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animate-out {
    animation-name: menue-out;
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menue-in {
    from { transform: translateX(-100%);}
    to { transform: translateX(0%);}
  }
@keyframes menue-out {
    from { transform: translateX(0%);}
    to { transform: translateX(-100%);}
}

.navigation__mobile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle">click</button>
<div class="navigation__mobile">
navaigation
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work... –

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `animation-fill-mode` property here. So If you will not use this property then the element will come to the original/default position.
But we do not want that so here you can use the `animation-mode-fill: forwards` property so that element can retain its last position.

Here is the updated css code:

```
.animate-in {
  animation-name: menue-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animate-out {
  animation-name: menue-out;
  animation-duration: 1s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menue-in {
  from { transform: translateX(-100%);}
  to { transform: translateX(0%);}
}
@keyframes menue-out {
    from { transform: translateX(0%);}
    to { transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

Comment: it does not work...

Comment: @MarcoDev but "coding monster' already provided you a working example. It should work but still if you are facing problem then can you provide your code in codepan.io or somewhere else so I can find problem in your code.

Comment: I have updated the Code

Comment: @MarcoDev there is no problem in your updated css code, javascript code is also looks good. Problem is somewhere else maybe in some other css property or in some other part of your code. So if you will provide a complete code which will include html as well as other css property and js code too then it will be easier to find the problem. That is why create  a sample of your code in codepan.io or you can upload your code to GitHub.